# wpdb num_rows return always 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form created with gravity forms (wordpress) and taking as input the "card number" and the email I want to see if the data associated with a user. I tried to make me return the number of rows in the query, but num_rows always returns 0. The "card number" is in the table usermeta.It copies the function code created.

```
function ricerca_fc_from_db($entry, $form) {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta wpusermeta
          FULL JOIN $wpdb->users wpusers ON (wpusermeta.user_id = wpusers.ID)
          WHERE wpusermeta.meta_value =".$entry[1]."
          AND  wpusers.user_email ='".$entry[2]."'
          AND wpusermeta.user_id = wpusers.ID");

    $row = $wpdb->num_rows;
    if($row == 0) {
    } else {
        header("location: http://stackoverflow.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: echo your query and make sure it will returning results.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but please never use global variable... this is nightmare for every developer. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil Just wanted to make world a bit better

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why that is.

Comment: I think this is just not the way to go with wordpress. Take a look at the [WP User Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) and [WP Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) and [WP User Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)